# Copy file to remote location throws network path not found intermittently

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am trying to copy a file generated (Excel file) by my c# code into a remote network path to which I have access as below:

```
string folder = "\\\\testing-path\\Audit\\Reports";
if (!(Directory.Exists(folder + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "\\" + "Audit")))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "\\" + "Audit");
}
folder = folder + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "\\" + "Audit";

if (File.Exists(folder + "\\Audit- " + fname + ".xlsx"))
{
    File.Delete(folder + "\\Audit- " + fname + ".xlsx");
}
string fileName = folder + "\\Audit- " + fname + ".xlsx";
wb.SaveAs(fileName,
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, null, null,
    false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    null, null, null, null, null);
```

This code works perfectly fine 8/10 times and throws network error (Network path not found) other 2 times. When the remote path throws this error I open the above remote path using run command on the machine I run this code and I am able to access it as normal. Closing the folder opened manually and re-running the code is solving the issue. What could be the issue? Am I doing something wrong here?

PS: I also tried to save the excel file onto desktop and then use `File.Copy` and there is no change to this intermittent behaviour.

Comment: Hello - did you ever find a resolution or cause? I have a similar issue in a production system - although it happens rarely.

Comment: I havent found a solution but the work around would be to open the folder and close it and then do the above logic

Answer (score 1):

Check the following things

```
1) First you have to check whether machine is on or off
2) Then check you have access rights to put the file in that particular folder and dont
   put it inside ' C ' Drive because C is not accessible for other users in network put it inside D or E drive.
3) If Folder is Missing You have to Create A Folder first
```

and what is ' WB  '

```
 if(!Directory.Exists("\\\\testing-path\\Audit\\Reports"))
    Directory.Create("\\\\testing-path\\Audit\\Reports");
```

Use

```
                                                          FilePath     Byte 

 File.ReadAllBytes("FilePath/FileName.Extension",byte) //  D:\\Test.xls,12878
```

then in Remote Location
                                                               FilePath     Byte

```
 File.WriteAllBytes("FilePath/FileName.Extension",byte)//   D:\\Test123.xls,12878
```

Check this Link

Accessing paths in Remote Machine : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184633/Connect-to-a-shared-folder-using-ip-address-in-vb6

Comment: 1) The machine is on, I am able to open that path from run
2)its not on C drive so no issues
3)I am creating a folder if the folder doesnt exists.

Wb is excel workbook which I am trying to save. I tried all types of copies but they didnt work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No luck, still the same issue :(

Comment: D:\\Test123.xls hardcode this value instead of \\\\testing-path\\Audit\\Reports

Comment: As mentioned, I am trying to copy the file to remote location and not to a local file